# Cannot access Collection::$items

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've got some troubles with an eloquent query.

Users have many feeds and feeds have many items.

I need to get all the items that belongs to the feeds of the user order by date.

I've got a pivot table:

```
feed_user
----------

 - id
 - feed_id
 - user_id
```

and relationships are defined like this in my models:

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {


public function feeds() {
    return $this->hasMany('feed');
}


class Feed extends \Eloquent {

protected $fillable = [];

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}

public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany('Item');
}

class Item extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [];

public function feed() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Feed');
}
```

But when I do this query...

```
Auth::user()->feeds->items->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
```

It returns this error:

```
Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple issues here.

First, the relationship on User model is not correct. A hasMany relationship is one half a one-to-many relationship.  This would assume that a feed belongs to one user, and that the feed table has the user_id field.  A many-to-many relationship is defined by adding a belongsToMany relationship on both models.  So, a user belongsToMany feeds, and a feed belongsToMany users.

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    public function feeds() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('feed');
    }
}
```

Next, the error you're seeing is because `Auth::user()->feeds` returns a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object.  You're then trying to access the `items` attribute on the Collection, which is protected and throws the error you're seeing.

Finally, since Laravel does not use joins for relationships, you cannot order a query by a field on a related table without manually doing the join yourself.

Comment: Many thanks ! I've managed to return an object with all the items of the feed like this:

$feeds = Auth::user()->feeds;
  $contents = new ArrayObject;
  foreach($feeds as $feed) {
   $items = Item::where('feed_id', $feed->id)->with('Feed')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
   foreach($items as $item){
    $contents[] = $item;
   }
  }

But I don't know how to sort the result by date. Maybe I need to ask another question ?

Comment: @vali2009 There are some easier ways to do what you're trying to do here.  I think it'd be better for you to ask a new question.  One specific note, though: there is no need to query the item like that.  Inside your foreach, `$feed` is a Feed model, so you can access its items via `$feed->items`.

Comment: Well, again, many thanks for your help, Laravel and oriented object coding is new for me so I don't think to this kind of "shortcuts". I'm gonna ask a new question, because i've already tried to sort my big item's object return, without success. It's a little bit tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Try using eager loading:

```
Auth::user()->with('feeds.items')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @bogdan but it returns a new error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::items()

Comment: Now it generate this SQL: select * from `users` order by `date` desc. I need to sort the items by date, not the users, how can I do ? Thanks for your help.